# How to resize canvas with javascript to pixel amount

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, yii

I am trying to resize the canvas width to a given pixel amount like this:

```
if (condition==true) {
    canvasVar.width = pixel amount;
}
```

The if statement is executing, but the canvas is resizing weird. I've tried a number of methods:

```
var canvasVar = document.getElementById('canvasId');
var contextVar = canvasVar.getContext('2d');

//all numbers in pixels.
canvasVar.style.width = 20; //doesn't do anything.
canvasVar.width = 20; //resizes the HEIGHT!!!
contextVar.canvas.width = 20; //also resizes height.
```

The canvas width/height values after method 2 & 3 are appiled are 656 (normal value) & 1405 (normal value = 328).

NOTE: I am setting canvas default width/height with CSS and I am also using the Yii PHP framework.

Thanks.

EDIT: I've also tried to follow `20` by the `px` extension. Gives an error saying 'unexpected identifier'.

Comment: can you  post js fiddle showing the problem

Comment: I tried what you said with jsfiddle and `canvasVar.width = 20;` worked PERFECT. I am using a bunch of other technologies that might be affecting this including one called [chart js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/).

Comment: it's always to isolate things when debugging then put them all together. Saves your time and frustration

Answer (score 1):

A canvas has "2" height and width properties. One of them specifiesthe resolution of the canvas, the other the size

```
canvasVar[0].width = 20; // canvas consists of 20 virtual px in width
canvasVar[0].style.width = '400 px' // canvas gets a width of 400 px
```

Comment: When I added the array bracets it gave me this: `Cannot set property 'width' of undefined`. I also tried to do the style suggestion you were saying (putting it in quotes) and it had no effect.